# Reading Little Endian – LS Byte first for integer how to ignore the extra 0

Tags: java, endianness

I have been reading these byte by bytes from streams. Example I read this line like this.

```
int payloadLength = r.readUnsignedShort();
```

The problem I have is that 2 bytes value is `x3100` so it turns out to be 12544 but I suppose to only read as `x31` which makes it to be only `49`. How to ignore the extra 00.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please mark hex numbers, like 0x31 is 49.

Comment: @Why is this is down vote when its relevant question and some answers are given too?

Comment: Please read the guidelines for asking a good question. Your last paragraph is extremely confusion. You don't show a real code sample. You don't give example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @NomadMaker so I can correct the question to make it better. I have edit the question so can you remove the down vote ?

Comment: Why aren't you reading bytes directly from your source, which I'm assuming is a java.io.InputStream subclass? Had you give a larger code sample, I wouldn't have had to guess.

Comment: @Nomadmaker actually I am reading directly from my input stream but I go accordingly to the documents for example first 2 will be packet size, then next 4 will be id, then next 16 will be imei but then there is also some parts are dynamic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right shift the value by 8 bits and then and it with 0xFF. Right shifting moves the bits 8 bits to the right. Any other bits would also be moved to the right so you need to mask those of by do an ANDing (`&`) with 0xFF to get rid of them.

```
    int payloadLength = r.readUnsignedShort();

    payloadLength = (payloadLength >>> 8)& 0xFF;
    System.out.println(payLoadLength);
```

You may also want to swap the two bytes.

```
    v = 0xa0b;
    v = swapBytes(v);
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(v)); // 0xb0a


    public static int swapBytes(int v) {
        return ((v << 8)&0xFF00) | ((v >> 8) & 0xFF);
    }
```

Normally, for reading in just 16 bits you would not have to and it with `0xFF` since the high order bits are 0's.  But I think it is a good practice and will prevent possible problems in the future.

Comment: I found another method int intBodyLen = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytePacketLength).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();. I think this works even for other size of buffer ?